# Asp.net MVC é melhor trabalhar com Áreas ou com Projetos dentro de uma Solution?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estou criando um portal e separando os módulos por Áreas.

Mas as demandas estão aumentando muito, já tem pelo menos mais 5 módulos a serem escritos no portal.

Qual é o melhor caminho a seguir em termos de performace e organização? Continuar no padrão MVC separando os módulos por áreas ou separar por projetos dentro da Solution?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: `Areas` em projetos e "diferentes projetos" na mesma solutions são coisas bem diferentes. Ao criar `Areas`, tudo fica organizado na mesma aplicação Web, ou seja, mesmo `DNS`, mesmo "site", ao criar projetos separados, cada um será um "site" diferente, aplicações diferentes, e `DNS` diferentes, tem que pensar em qual cenário se aplica melhor no seu caso.

Comment: @RicardoPontual o cenário é um portal que possui diversos módulos. Um endereço com vários tipos de acessos diferentes. Por exemplo: O rapaz da portaria terá que acessar o portal mas usará apenas o módulo que lhe é permitido.

Comment: @RicardoPontual eu sei que também conseguiríamos separar as áreas em projetos e apontar para o mesmo DNS. Mas minha dúvida é . Vale a pena e porque?

Comment: É uma questão meio pessoal, mas eu trabalhei num projeto assim (areas em multiplos projetos) e não gostei, demorei um tempo pra descobrir que os projetos estavam relacionados e que as rotas tinha namespace.... se os sites vão compartilhar `css` e `javascript` faz mais sentido, *na minha humilde opinião*, deixar no mesmo projeto, agora se eles precisam ser mais independentes, talvez separar em diferentes projetos faça mais sentido.

Comment: @RicardoPontual. Sabes me dizer se há limites para criação de áreas? Se por ventura crescer bastante eu perderia performace?

Comment: Boa pergunta, não sei se há limites, fiquei curioso e pesquisei mas não achei nada falando sobre uma limitação

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do ponto de vista técnico, colocar em outro projetos gera pontos positivos e negativos. 
Ponto positivo:

- Colocar em projetos diferentes você ira modularizar mais seu sistema. Como vantagem disso, você pode **parar um projeto enquanto os outros continuam funcionando**. Ex: A área de expedição pode ser parada para manutenção enquanto a portaria continua funcionando. 
  Há um nome pra esse tipo de abordagem de desenvolvimento: **Microsserviço**.

Pontos negativo:

- A **complexidade de seu projeto vai aumentar**. Você terá que manipular login nos dois, configurar dois projetos no IIS, manipular DNS, consumirá mais recursos do servidor etc.

Na minha opinião, do ponto de vista organizacional não muda, você os separou em pastas internamente.

No quesito performance, só poderíamos ter certeza de uma **performance melhor**, caso **cada projeto seja colocado em um servidor diferente**. 
Se eles forem colocados no mesmo servidor, apenas via testes de stress e banchmarks teriamos como saber. Mesmo assim, **provável que não dê grandes diferenças por estarem no mesmo servidor**.

Então **cabe a você** analisar os pontos positivos e negativos técnicos e decidir o que melhor se enquadra pra você ou sua equipe. Se o aumento da escabilidade do microsserviço compensa o aumento da complexibilidade do sistema.